# java - Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell Exception

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm currently getting the hang of using the Apache POI and I'm currently trying to import a .xlsx and store it into an ArrayList but the problem is I seem to be getting an exception error that says "Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell". This is the message specifically.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcZb0.png)

I'm pretty sure the value of the cell is has a NUMERIC value.

```
    private void AddButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel file","xlsx", "xls"); 
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileFilter(filter);
    fc.setDialogTitle("Excel file selector");
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(mainMenuPanel);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        jDialogaddItem.setVisible(true);
        try{
            ArrayList<Item> itemList2 = new ArrayList<>();
            Item item2;
            String filepath = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(filepath));
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();                
                    item2 = new Item(cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getStringCellValue(), (int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    itemList2.add(item2);    
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

My excel file looks like this

[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HOyc.png)

Comment: You only call `Cell cell = cellIterator.next();` **once** before doing `cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getStringCellValue(),cell.getStringCellValue(), (int)cell.getNumericCellValue()`, so you are trying to get the same cell 5 times: 4 times as string value and 1 time as numeric value. You cannot have yor Item creation inside the cell iteration loop. (Because obviously you want to create an Item for every row, not for every single cell)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the suggestion and I applied it to my code, but the exception is still there though. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Get it as string and convert it:

```
Integer.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue())
```

else in excel you should have your cell with numeric format

Comment: But my cell in excel is already in numeric format, thats why im confused as to why the exception says that the cell is in string format